# How to pass an array through a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

I am working on some code where a user can create clients that all have a first name, last name, phone number, etc... I would like to add a button where the user can enter multiple notes about the client's family but don't know how they would be added to the client, if that makes sense. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
function client(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, address, hireDate, frequency, cost, entry) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.address = address;
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.entry = entry;
}
var laura = new client("laura", "simmerman", "1111111111", "laura rd", "01/01/01", "weekly", "100", "garage-1111");
var clients = [laura];
```

So basically to get the first client's first name I would use: clients[0].firstName;

What I want to do in add an array called familyNotes as another parameter, like so:

```
function client(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, address, hireDate, frequency, cost, entry, familyNotes[]) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.address = address;
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.entry = entry;
    this.familyNotes = familyNotes[];
}
```

Then to get the first note I would call: clients[0].familyNotes[0];

However this doesn't seem to work, am I calling the array incorrectly? Can anyone tell me a way to have an array as a parameter in this situation?

Comment: just remove the brackets "[ ]"

Comment: You don't need the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets when passing the parameter

```
function client(firstName, ... ,  familyNotes) { // no brackets after familyNotes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function client(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, address, hireDate, frequency, cost, entry, familyNotes) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.address = address;
    this.hireDate = hireDate;
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.entry = entry;
    this.familyNotes = familyNotes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As user2887596 said, you need to remove the square brackets in the function declaration `function client(firstName, ... ,  familyNotes) {` but also when you assign the property to `this`

Should be `this.familyNotes = familyNotes;`